# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.3 Release and i have problem while instantiating `org.elasticsearch.client.Client`. My code:

```
Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", clustername)
                .build())
                .addTransportAddress(
new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port)
);
```

This code give me the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/transport/Netty3Plugin
at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<clinit>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:91) ~[transport-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at kz.icode.idmatrix.config.ElasticsearchConfiguration.client(ElasticsearchConfiguration.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
at kz.icode.idmatrix.config.ElasticsearchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e53ae93.CGLIB$client$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at kz.icode.idmatrix.config.ElasticsearchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e53ae93$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fef36179.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at kz.icode.idmatrix.config.ElasticsearchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e53ae93.client(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
... 99 common frames omitted
```

I use `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:5.6.10` and `org.elasticsearch.client:client:5.6.10`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not all dependencies are satisfied by only adding `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`.

It's necessary to explicitly define all remaining dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you've declared a parent, most likely `<version>` tag can be omitted.

Comment: In my case, this is the only part I need to add:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Comment: They are all satisfied now. In my case I had to upgrade my spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.3.3.RELEASE (I had 2.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId> 
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

This is resolved for me.