# Spring Boot 2.0.1 + JPA+Elasticsearch gives error nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/querydsl/QueryDslUtils

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '2.4.5'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: '2.1.9.RELEASE'
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.1.0.Final"
compile("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:${liquibase_core_version}") {
    exclude(module: 'jetty-servlet')
}
compile "com.mattbertolini:liquibase-slf4j:${liquibase_slf4j_version}"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"){
    exclude(module: 'hibernate-core')
    //exclude(module: 'spring-data-jpa')
}
//compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-releasetrain', version: 'Lovelace-SR1', ext: 'pom'
compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.0.9.RELEASE"
```

Comment: I have added org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.0.9.RELEASE which contains QueryDslutil

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039938/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-elasticsearch-transport-netty3p

Comment: Stop mixing versions. Don't exclude hibernate and remove the `org.springframework.data` dependencies. Leave only the starters. Add `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` as a dependency. That way you have unified version management.

Comment: Thanks deinum, But spring starter elasticsearch 2.0.1 gives elasticsearch version 5.6.10 which spring does not work with. Please refer https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix